# How to update alpinejs component from js code

Tags: alpine.js

I have an input name address (created by a plugin in WordPress context).

When I type some text in this input, I would like to modify an alpine component (new dropdown component used for autocompletion).

Before I used that :

```
address.addEventListener('input', _.debounce(event => callApi(event.target.value), 250));
```

Instead of calling callApi function, i need to act on the toggle.

In the dropdown component, I can add :

> @set-title.window="title = $event.detail"

but how from my debounce, call the toggle ?

I should be able to do $dispatch('set-title', 'Hello World!') somewhere ?

I specify that I cannot modify my basic input (perhaps in javascript)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event listener inside the Alpine.js component's `init()` method and mutate the `title` variable from there:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="address" />
</div>

<div x-data="myComponent">
  <div x-text="title"></div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('myComponent', () => ({
    title: '',
    init() {
      const address = document.getElementById('address')
      address.addEventListener('input', _.debounce(event => {this.title = event.target.value}, 250)
      });
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```